# Irrelevant post and review on my website

Tags: search

Reviews and post from customers for a juice center are getting posted in the Google maps which aren't relevant to my business profile. The juice center is below my office apartment. Please assist how to fix

Comment: Is your name and address presented clearly on your site? Have you flagged the reviews? If you're not signed up for Google My Business, you should do so and request [Support for Reviews and Photos](https://support.google.com/business/?hl=en#topic=4539639&contact=1).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with it that you must relocate your Google My Business pin from the exact spot to the back of the pin which is getting reviews, not relevant to your business.

Google my business acts weird when two pins are located closely with each other, you need to relocate that to solve the problem.

Since you got some irrelevant reviews, it is best to reply to all of them and make them aware that you're not the business they think you are. Make replies public so people in the future can also read it.